# Hbase concurrency making it slow

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have 1 master server and 5 region server and each server has 200 GB disk space and 16 GB RAM on each. I created a table in HBase which has 10 million records. I am using hbase-0.96 version on hadoop 2.

Table Name -  sh_self_profiles

column family - profile

In this table, we have 30 columns in each row.
When I get a single column value from HBase, it takes around 10 ms. My problem is when I hit 100 or more concurrent requests the time slowly accumulates and increases to more than 400 ms instead of completing in 10ms only. When 100 requests are hit linearly, each one takes 10 ms only.

Comment: add more info on your key design, memory settings for hbase etc.

Comment: How big are the records? Are they 100 million 1MB records or are they 10 byte records? That makes a big difference.

Comment: How are the reads distributed? Uniformly? Are you accessing the same row over and over again?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you should check is how well distributed your table is.

You can do this by going to the HBase master web console http://:60010, you will be able to see how many regions you have for your table. If you have not done anything special on table creation you could easily have only one or two regions, which means that all the requests are being directed to a single region server.

If this is the case, you can recreate your table with pre-split regions (I would suggest a multiple of 5, such as 15 or 20), and make sure that the concurrent gets that you are doing are equally spread over the row-key space.

Also, pls check how much RAM you have allocated to the region server - you might need to increase it from the default. If you are not running anything else other than HBase Region Sever on those machines, you could probably increase to 8GB ram.

Other than that, you could also adjust the default for hbase.regionserver.handler.count.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Which client are you using? Are you using the standard Java client, the Thrift client, the HTTP REST client, or something else? If your use case is a high amount of random reads of single column values, I highly recommend you try [asynchbase](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/asynchbase) as it is much faster than the standard synchronous Java client.